# Why is `ls` command not permitted in non-root account even using `sudo`?

Tags: linux, ls

I logged into Ubuntu with guest session account, but the `ls` command is not permitted even using `sudo`.

[image]

But... why? Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your user account not included in sudoers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're not a `sudoer`. Which is a list of users allowed to use the `sudo` command.

You can become a `sudoer` by adding your username to the list of `sudoer` as root:

1. Become root by: `su` and entering root's password
2. `visudo` (Brings up a comamndline text editor specifically for editing the `sudoers` file)
3. Add this line to the bottom of the list: `YOUR_USERNAME_HERE ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Comment: To answer the other half of the question - why isn't `ls` working? - it's because the guest account doesn't have read permission for the `/home` directory. By default (reading from an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM), only the owner has permission to do anything with the `/home` directory (its permissions show up as `drwx------` for me). [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) offers a more thorough explanation of file permissions.